# Как в Postman написать тест который проверит есть ли в ответе строка кода?

Tags: javascript, postman

Например проверить, что в теле ответа есть вот такая строчка
`<!-- Google Tag Manager -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```js
pm.test("Body have GTM ", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("<!-- Google Tag Manager -->");
});
```

UPD: дополнил по просьбе из комментариев

```js
pm.test("Body have meta with content-type", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`);
});
```

Ссылки-помощники:

- [Postman: Writing tests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/)
- [Postman: Test script examples](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/)

Comment: а если стока будет такой <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> то не сработает 
https://clip2net.com/s/4byk3lL

Comment: Разобрался. спасибо большое! Просто добавил экранирование символа " через \

Comment: Дополнил ответ как можно обойтись без \ :)

Comment: Круто! Вы лучший)